# Remove element when it has a specified child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

How can I delete list element if it has a child link of some defined id ? So looking at the code below I'd like to find a `<li>` with `<a>` of `id=link1` and delete this `li`.

```
<li class="nav-tab">
    <a href="#link1">Component</a>
</li>
```

I've tried the code below but it doesn't work :

```
 $(function() {
     $('.nav-tab:has(#link1)').css('display', 'none');
 });
```

Comment: That's not an `a id="link1"`, that's an anchor link to `somethingelse id="link1"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question and your code contradict each other, so I'll provide answers for both cases.

If you want to remove a `<li class="nav-tab">` that contains a child `<a href="#link1">`:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href="#link1"]').parent('li.nav-tab').remove();
});
```

If you want to remove a `<li class="nav-tab">` that contains a child `<a id="link1">`:

```
$(function() {
    $('a#link1').parent('li.nav-tab').remove();
});
```

Comment: Nick Craver's answer is closer to what you tried since you use `:has()` by the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [attribute-equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) to see if it contains an element matching that...then just call [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) on that.

```
$("li:has(a[href='#link1'])").remove()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function() {
     $(".nav-tab > a[id='yourID']").css('display', 'none');
 });
```

If by anchor :

```
$(function() {
     $(".nav-tab > a[href='yourLink']").css('display', 'none');
 });
```

Comment: No, that selects and hides the `a` elements as opposed to the `li` elements.

Comment: You're right, just copied the previous one, correct code is : `$(".nav-tab > a[href='yourLink']").closest('li').remove()`